# How to change data value in SQLAlchemy database on Flask Python site?

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a simple flask python site, the basic idea being the user receives 1 point every time they press a button. There's a simple login system that I'll later add a password to.

Currently, I'm having trouble changing the value of my *score* column in the SQLAlchemy database for a user when they press the button. Here's the code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session, flash
from datetime import timedelta
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "nicetry"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///users.sqlite3'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=5)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class users(db.Model):
    _id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100)) 
    email = db.Column(db.String(100))
    score = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, name, email, score):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.score = score


@app.route("/clicker")
def clicker():
    return render_template("clicker.html") #This opens a page with a button, when the button is clicked it runs buttonclick() below:

@app.route('/buttonclick', methods=['POST']) 
def buttonclick():
    print("button pressed")
    # HERE!
    return 'Success'
```

Not shown is the rest of the site, including the sign-in process in which a user enters username and email address, and the HTML/CSS that's really basic.

I'm not sure how to format the UPDATE line of code, (marked with **# HERE!** in the block above). Most of this database stuff is entirely sourced through a tutorial, and I'm still learning more about how it works. How would I change the user's score by one each time they press the button (buttonclick())?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To update the user score.First, you need call api with user_id. Then find the user by user_id and update score.

```
@app.route('/buttonclick', methods=['POST'])
def buttonclick():
    # you can use in on path ex /<int:user_id>/buttonclick
    user_id = request.json.get("user_id")
    # find user by id, use with_for_update() to lock query, avoid multi request coming 
    user = users.query.filter_by(_id=user_id).with_for_update().first()
    user.score += 1
    db.session.commit()
    return 'Success'
```